# Text field group validation using jquery validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Currently working with jquery group field validation. I am using the great jquery validation plugin I have searched through SO actually I got some idea for group validation with my current code I can able to validate the three field and when i typed in any of the field the errClass getting disappear but the validation count was not detecting.

I was not able to figure out what was the problem

Here is the jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
$(".error_msge").hide();
  $(".basicForm").validate({
   ignore: false,
     onkeyup: false,
        showErrors: function (errorMap, errorList) {
        var errors = this.numberOfInvalids();

        if (errors) {
            var message = errors == 1 ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted' : 'You have missed ' + errors + ' fields. Please fill the highlited field before submit.';
            $("#error_message").html(message);
            $(".error_msge").show();
        } else {
            $(".error_msge").hide();
        }
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
    errorPlacement: function () {
        return false;
    },
    highlight: function (element) {

        if ($(element).is(':radio'))  {

        } else {
            $(element).addClass('errRed');
        }
        $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-red').removeClass('text-error-black');            
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {

        if ($(element).is(':radio')) {
        } else {
            $(element).removeClass('errRed');
        }
        $(element).prevAll('label').find('span.required-star').addClass('text-error-black').removeClass('text-error-red');

    },

    rules: {
        txt_Po: {
              require_from_group: [1, ".txt_Add"]
            },
            txt_Bdg: {
              require_from_group: [1, ".txt_Add"]
            },
            txt_St: {
              require_from_group: [1, ".txt_Add"]
            }

    }
});
});
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<span id="error_message" class="error_msge">

            </span>
<form autocomplete="off" class="basicForm" id="basicForm" method="POST">
<!--first field-->
<label>P.O.Box</label>
                      <br/>
                      <input type="text" class="ipt_Field txt_Add" id="txt_Po" name="txt_Po" />
    <!--second field-->
 <label>Building</label>
                      <br/>
                      <input type="text" class="ipt_Field txt_Add" id="txt_Bdg" name="txt_Bdg" />
    <!--third field-->
<label>Street</label>
                      <br/>
                      <input type="text" class="ipt_Field txt_Add" id="txt_St" name="txt_St" />
<button class="btn-next" id="btn-Next" >Next</button>
</form>
```

Here is the CSS code

```
.errRed {
color: black !important;
border: 1px solid #EA373D !important;
padding: 6px !important;
}
.error_msge {
    border:1px solid red;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFBABA!important;
    padding: 5px;
 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the problem is not with the count, the problem > click next > 3 invalid inputs > fill the value and error count works till 3rd input value inserted> all looks good but at this point if i remove value from any input, and click next button , it will move to next step without validating the blank input

Comment: anyone wants to solve this problem, here is a quick start http://jsfiddle.net/wo55x3x1/

Comment: any suggestion for the above question